# I can increase my skills beyond 100% in Original Fallout?

Tags: fallout

I'm used to only being able to incease my skills (Small Guns, Big Guns, Sneak, Barter etc) to 100% and no more in Fallout 3 and NV (At least, I think that's the case...), however, in the original Fallout there appears to be no cap at all on how high I can raise these skills. I love Big Guns, but I've refrained from putting > 100% into it because I'm afraid it won't make a difference.

The game's great but a bit glitchy which I why I've refrained. Can I keep plugging away at Big Guns and will my character become beyond ninja regarding Big Guns?

Comment: I believe the maximum for the skills in FO and FO2 is 300%, but it has been a while since I've played them. However, after a certain level the percentage increase per point will decrease, making it more expensive to keep increasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Per Jorner of [The Nearly Ultimate Fallout Guide](http://user.tninet.se/~jyg699a/fallout.html), you will see some benefit in investing skill points into combat skills until you get the maximum 95% chance to hit.

> As a rule, it's not worth it to raise most skills above 100%. Combat
>   skills can be improved beyond that for an extra edge until you reach
>   the point where you get the maximum 95% chance to hit against all
>   opponents and from any reasonable range (which takes a bit longer if
>   you practice the art of aimed shots or blows). Even if you raise Sneak
>   and Steal to their maximum values you'll still get caught a lot,
>   suggesting your chance of success is capped at 95% before negative
>   modifiers are applied (in fact, testing shows no significant
>   difference between Steal 30% and Steal 200% under pretty normal
>   circumstances). Note however that it doesn't cost more skill points to
>   raise a skill at high skill levels.